# Lodash is taking 2x the size in Rollup bundle

Tags: javascript, typescript, lodash, rollup, rollupjs

I'm working on a TS React library to be used in another project I have. This library is being bundled with Rollup. I noticed that my bundle size was quite big, so I used [rollup-plugin-visualizer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rollup-plugin-visualizer) to help me see what was taking all space. One thing that struck me as weird was that [Lodash](https://bundlephobia.com/package/lodash@4.17.21) was taking 2x the size it was supposed to (142KB instead of 69.9KB).

I've gone through my tsconfig.json and rollup.config.js and can't find the reason for it.. Perhaps someone has an idea of why this is happening? I know I can use a minifier like Terser to reduce the bundle size, but I'm mostly interested in understanding why this is happening in the first place.

Some caveats:

- In my project I'm only importing the lodash modules I need (`import map from 'lodash/map';`) to get the smallest bundle size, but unfortunately one of my dependencies (a 3rd party interactive charts library) imports the whole thing.
- I also ran `npm ls lodash` and verified that there is only 1 version of lodash and all the other usages are deduped.

Thank you for your help! Here are the config files:

`tsconfig.json`

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "declaration": true,
    "declarationDir": "build",
    "module": "esnext",
    "target": "es2018",
    "lib": [ "dom", "es2017"],
    "sourceMap": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "moduleResolution": "classic",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*", "src/declaration.d.ts"],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "build",
    "src/**/*.stories.tsx",
    "src/**/*.test.tsx"
  ]
}
```

`rollup.config.js`

```js
import commonjs from '@rollup/plugin-commonjs'
import image from '@rollup/plugin-image'
import peerDepsExternal from 'rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external'
import postcss from 'rollup-plugin-postcss'
import resolve from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve'
import typescript from 'rollup-plugin-typescript2'
import { visualizer } from 'rollup-plugin-visualizer'

const packageJson = require('./package.json')

export default {
  input: 'src/index.ts',
  output: [
    {
      file: packageJson.main,
      format: 'cjs',
      sourcemap: true,
    },
    {
      file: packageJson.module,
      format: 'esm',
      sourcemap: true,
    },
  ],
  plugins: [
    peerDepsExternal(),
    resolve({ preferBuiltins: true }),
    commonjs(),
    typescript({ useTsconfigDeclarationDir: true }),
    postcss(),
    image({
      extensions: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|svg)$/,
      limit: 10000,
    }),
    visualizer(),
  ],
}
```

[image: Screenshot of the Visualizer output]